# ASP Net Core Azure B2C API downstream call to my Api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create authenticated downstream call from my user facing application to my api application.

Both applications register B2C as authorization provider. User facing application is SPA and correctly validates token as being api as well. I have configured B2C that user facing application has delegated permission to api application.

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(
                    context.Configuration,
                    Constants.AzureAdB2C,
                    subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Not working approahc 1:

I tried to make downstream api on behalf of user like this. Below example fails with exception that could not parse json unvalid first character '<'.

```
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpService, MyHttpService>((services, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:5050";
        })
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUserAuthenticationHandler("router", options =>
        {
            options.IsProofOfPossessionRequest = false;
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer";
            options.Tenant = "<my tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com";
            options.Scopes = "<app uri id>/.admin"; // this is scope for user to have access to application endpoint
             });
```

Not working approahc 2:

This approach succsessfully gets the token inside web application, but when token travels to the api application it rejects the token with user must be authenticated error message. Here I also ave found weird behavior. I noticed that api is validating received Bearer token and it is getting passed to api application. When I pass invalid token with different authority it correctly mentions it, yet in this case I just get must have authenticated user exception same as no token would be provided.

```
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpService, MyHttpService>((services, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:5050";
        })
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityAppAuthenticationHandler("router", options =>
        {
            options.IsProofOfPossessionRequest = false;
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer";
            options.Tenant = "<my tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com";
            options.Scopes = "<app uri id>/.default";
             });
```

Ideally I want to create on behalf of authentication from user facing application to api. I have read that B2C does not support it yet, so I tried to create deamon approach for authentication, but I have failed thus far. My goal is to secure api microservice using b2c any built in methods.